# How to structure a new project in maven so it finds jar files and doesn't give dependency errors

Tags: java, maven

TIL like I'm 5. I am not a developer. I've downloaded two udemy courses on maven and gone through both as well as gone through http://maven.apache.org/guides and nothing I've gone through really explains how to set up a project with a local (not remote) repo and what to configure and I'm getting embarrassed at how long I've spent today on trying to figure this out.

My senior person has set up a project that has the main framework things I need to plug in my scripts to run automation. I'm creating feature files/step def files on a certain project and it all uses her UI framework project with the webdriver/properties information I need. She's compiled this project in a jar file: CoreAutomationLibrary-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Then I try to run a maven install on my project to get an initial build success so I can go through with creating my more tailored scripts.

Here is my current POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MyAutomation</groupId>
<artifactId>MyAutomation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MyAutomation</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>CoreAutomationLibrary</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoreAutomationLibrary</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm not sure where to put this jar file.
For instance, I have her project downloaded to:
Users/myName/eclipse-workspace/HerProject
And I have my project downloaded to:
Users/myName/eclipse-workspace/RestAssured/MyProject

This jar file is floating around now, I keep moving it. I had it in my project folder just independent of anything. I tried putting it target. I'm not sure where it goes. I thought the important thing was just that it was in the build path for the project, which it is.

When I run maven install:

```
WARNING] The POM for CoreAutomationLibrary:CoreAutomationLibrary:jar:0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 ---
[INFO] Total time: 0.221 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-22T11:32:44-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/243M
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project COM_UI: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project COM_UI:COM_UI:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find 
artifact CoreAutomationLibrary:CoreAutomationLibrary:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> 
[Help 1]
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with selenium and cucumber?

Answer (score 2):

Maven usually deals with downloading dependencies itself. Propably the easiest solution in the long run is to host a repository manager like [Nexus](https://de.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/). Then you can configure your local maven to use this as a repository.

If this is not possible for you, you have to [install the jar to your local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) using

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=Users/myName/eclipse-workspace/HerProject/her.jar -DgroupId=CoreAutomationLibrary -DartifactId=CoreAutomationLibrary -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```